# Roleta com botão

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um botão que ao clicar nele ele altere a cor de um input.
Porém quero ficar alternando como se fosse uma roleta.
Eu clico no botão e ele altera a cor de um input, depois eu clico novamente ele altera de outro.
[Como nessa imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0EKE.png)

Comment: Tem diversas formas de se fazer. Seria interessante vc estudar e tentar fazer, e caso tenha alguma dificuldade envie aqui.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código, caso deseje que a roleta seja aleatória:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

let last = 0
function changeColor(){
    inputs[last].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    last = random(9);
    inputs[last].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+random(255)+','+random(255)+','+random(255)+')';
}


function random(mx, mn = 0) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (mx - mn) + mn);
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.center{
    text-align: center;
}
#inputs div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
input{
    width: 150px;
}
#inputs div{
    width: 100%;
}
button{
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
    <div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
        <div><input></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="center">
    <button onclick="changeColor()">Clique Aqui</button>
</div>
```

E caso deseje que a roleta siga a ordem dos inputs poderá alterar o código js para o seguinte

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

var last = 0;
var active = 0;
function changeColor(){
    if(last > 0){
        inputs[last-1].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
    last++;

    if(active >= inputs.length){
        last = 1;
        active = 0;
    }
    inputs[active].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb('+random(255)+','+random(255)+','+random(255)+')';
    active++;



}


function random(mx, mn = 0) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (mx - mn) + mn);
}
```